# laravel localization ignore language on one page

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, redirect, laravel-localization

Using mcamara laravel localization , for one specific page I need to ignore the language identifier.
Our project URLs are all in the form of  www.project.com/en|fr/page , for one page only we need to have the URL as www.project.com/example

I tried a few things in .htacess file, but couldn't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! It can be done in the routes page, you can identify which pages to be localized or not.